# What does `operator () { ... }` do in Dart?

Tags: dart, operator-overloading, operators

Here is a simple dart class:

```dart
class MyOperatorClass {
    int operator () {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

I noticed today that this compiles without any issues. This led me to wonder, what does `operator ()` mean?

Usually in dart, you use `operator` to implement, well, operators. Aka `operator +(other)` or `operator ~()`. But `operator ()` doesn't seem to *have* an operator associated with it...

At first I thought it was how you make objects callable, but as it turns out, `MyOperatorClass()()` doesn't compile (this is because callable objects actually implement the `call()` method). I asked ChatGPT about this and it was thoroughly confused, going back and forth on whether or not `operator ()` was a valid way to create callable objects, haha.

So if it's *not* how you create callable objects, but it *does* compile, what is it actually doing? When would it ever run?

Comment: Yeah, that's really confusing, but `operator` is not a keyword in this context. If you added a symbol after the word `operator` it would be one :) confusing but makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you're declaring an ordinary method that happens to be *named* `operator`.  You'd call it like any other named method:

```dart
void main() {
  var x = MyOperatorClass();
  print(x.operator()); // Prints: 5
}
```

From https://dart.dev/language/keywords, note that `operator` is listed with <sup>2</sup>:

> Words with the superscript **2** are **built-in identifiers**. These keywords are valid identifiers in most places, but they can’t be used as class or type names, or as import prefixes.

So `operator` apparently is legal as a method name (although using that would be ill-advised).

Comment: I see! I made a custom syntax highlighter for myself when writing Dart, and it recognized `operator` as a keyword in this context, so I totally forgot about this. I had gone through all of these identifier/keywords recently since I realized dart treated some words this way, but I guess I must have missed this case. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: That's why you should always use the official syntax highlighter source: the analyzer has an LSP interface.